# How do you write an Outlook Add-in that displays the sender's E-mail Address in a message box each time the user views an item?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

This is part of a larger project I'm working on, but for now I'm just trying to find a way to retrieve the sender's e-mail address each time the user clicks on a mail item in the inbox and its contents (the actual body of the e-mail) are displayed in the adjacent panel.

I tried writing code inside the `ItemLoad event handler` procedure, but even the MSDN website says that the Item object passed as an argument doesn't have its properties initialized, so calling (Item as MailItem).SenderEmailAddress will not work.

Can someone tell me how do this? (I'm using Outlook 2007)

The following, by the way, does not work:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, 
                         Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, 
                         object addInInst, 
                         ref System.Array custom)
{
    //this code runs
    applicationObject = (Outlook.Application)application;
    this.applicationObject.Startup += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_StartupEventHandler(applicationObject_Startup);
}

void applicationObject_Startup()
{
        //this code runs
        this.applicationObject.Explorers.NewExplorer += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(Explorers_NewExplorer);
}

void Explorers_NewExplorer(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer Explorer)
{
    //This code does not run
    Explorer.SelectionChange += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(Explorer_SelectionChange);
}

void Explorer_SelectionChange()
{
    //This code does not run
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it:

```
    public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
    {
        applicationObject = (Outlook.Application)application;
        this.applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(Explorer_SelectionChange);
    }
    void Explorer_SelectionChange()
    {
        if (applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem item = applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
               string address = item.SenderEmailAddress;
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this for a while, but I'm guessing you'll need to use the [`SelectionChange` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147654%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on the [`Explorer` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219946%28v=office.12%29.aspx) representing the main window.

In the [`Application.Startup` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147656%28v=office.12%29.aspx) handler, you'll need to get the [`Explorers` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220071%28v=office.12%29.aspx), and add a handler for the [`NewExplorer` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147643%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which will fire whenever the user opens a new window.

From there, you can hook the [`SelectionChange` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147654%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the new [`Explorer` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219946%28v=office.12%29.aspx), and in the handler for that event you'll be able to get the selected item(s) through the [`Selection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb206694%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You should then be able to get the sender's email address for each selected item.

Comment: It doesn't work. In the OnConnection event handler procedure I have this.applicationObject.Startup += ... (this event fires). and then inside the associated event handler procedure I have this.applicationObject.Explorers.NewExplorers += ... but the NewExplorers event never fires. In any case, inside that event handler procedure I have Explorer.SelectionChange += ... and then the actual code inside the associated event handler procedure, but as I said, it never fires.

Comment: ALso, I'm not sure that I want anything to fire when a new window is opened. I just want the event that fires when the user goes to his inbox, clicks on a mail item, and the contents of the item are displayed in the adjacent panel

Comment: OK, try handling the `ActiveExplorer.SelectionChange` event when the `Startup` event fires.